# How do I retrieve and update an azure configuration file for a service?

Tags: c#, xml, azure, configuration-files

i am completely new to Azure. I would like to be able to retrieve a services configuration file and then change the values within it. I am stuck at the very start as i do not know how go about editing the config file when it has been retrieved or what type (XMLDocument etc) it has to be set as to edit it. When i retrieve a services properties it returns the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HostedService xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure">
  <Url>hosted-service-url</Url>
  <ServiceName>hosted-service-name</ServiceName>
  <HostedServiceProperties>
    <Description>description</Description>
    <Location>location</Location>
    <AffinityGroup>affinity-group</AffinityGroup>
    <Label>base-64-encoded-name-of-the-service</Label>
  </HostedServiceProperties>
  <Deployments>
    <Deployment>
      <Name>deployment-name</Name>
      <DeploymentSlot>deployment-slot</DeploymentSlot>
      <PrivateID>deployment-id</PrivateID>
      <Status>deployment-status</Status>
      <Label>base64-encoded-deployment-label</Label>
      <Url>deployment-url</Url>
      <Configuration>base-64-encoded-configuration-file</Configuration>
      <RoleInstanceList>
        <RoleInstance>
          <RoleName>role-name</RoleName>
          <InstanceName>role-instance-name</InstanceName>
          <InstanceStatus>instance-status</InstanceStatus>
        </RoleInstance>
      </RoleInstanceList>
      <UpgradeDomainCount>upgrade-domain-count</UpgradeDomainCount>
      <RoleList>
        <Role>
          <RoleName>role-name</RoleName>
          <OsVersion>operating-system-version</OsVersion>
        </Role>
      </RoleList>
      <SdkVersion>sdk-version-used-to-create-package</SdkVersion>
      <InputEndpointList>
         <InputEndpoint>
            <RoleName>role-name</RoleName>
            <Vip>virtual-ip-address</Vip>
            <Port>port-number</Port>
         </InputEndpoint>
         …
      </InputEndpointList>
      <Locked>deployment-write-allowed-status</Locked>
      <RollbackAllowed>rollback-operation-allowed</RollbackAllowed>
    </Deployment>
  </Deployments>
</HostedService>
```

So like i said,what i want to do is take the "base-64-encoded-configuration-file" from this XML and edit its values. But i cannot figure out how to take the configuration file out of the above XML.

Any help or even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the source code for csmanage library.  It has the examples and abstraction layers for working with the Azure Service Management API: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-CSManage-e3f1882c

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately i am struggling to understand alot of that source code. I am only a beginner programmer. I was hoping it would be easier to do.

Answer (score 4):

You could also use the [Windows Azure Powershell Cmdlets](http://wappowershell.codeplex.com/).

Executing a *Set-DeploymentConfiguration* would update the configuration values of your instance.

You can find many tutorials on how to learn powershell online including:

- [Sean Kearney](http://www.powershell.ca/)
- [Hey Scripting Guy!](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/)
- [David Aiken](http://davidaiken.com/)